# Parsing font sizes from PDF files in Java

Tags: java, parsing, pdf, font-size

I need to write a program that can find the largest text in a PDF document (which is probably the title!), I've tried using [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) as a parser but I couldn't find a way to get the font size. Also the Tika library seems too powerful and complex for my use.
Is there an easier way/library that I can use? Is it easier or better to not use a library and parse the PDF myself (I am kinda interested in this approach)? If so, where should I start?

Any information is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6444178/242036) method on SO that overrides the `processTextPosition` from `PDFTextStripper` in the PDFBox library and extracts the font size. I didn't see it before because the post's question was a bit different.